# Responsive menu: undesirable link click on touch devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I've got a problem with responsive menu on mobile devices. The problem is that user simply can't scroll through menu items because when you put your finger on a link to scroll down (links are 100% width) - that link automatically opens at the same second, you just can't scroll down.

You can see it in action here: http://glebgrg4.bget.ru

Use mobile device with width < 768px to see the problem (you can open responsive menu via hamburger icon on top left corner of the header).

Is there any fix for this bug?

Comment: If the menu script itself is causing this, then you may want to check out: https://github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu/issues?q=

Comment: There's also a demo you can test and a link to an article for this plugin on https://github.com/codrops/MultiLevelPushMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the added event listener for touch is incorrect. Look at mlpushmenu.js line 98:
`this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';`

Try to set listener type 'touchstart' to 'touchend'.

Comment: That didn't really help me, because still when you scroll down it would open link you left your finger on when scrolling. But then I added 'click' instead of 'touchstart' and it worked perfectly for me.